# Page display error after changing base url

Tags: magento2, base-url

I am setting up a new Magento 2 store on AWS.

After installed M2 on my server (13.210.72.64), the site'base url was `13.210.72.64/magento2` and then I changed it to 13.210.72.64 in the admin panel(`configuration->web`). The site now is not working correctly.
I am pretty new to Magento 2.

Please help me out.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"? Where is the server root in relation to your magento2 folder? is your server root var/www/html and your Magento path var/www/html/magento2/index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your base URL in database you can find it on `core_config_data` table, If its not correct then please change it. If its correct (I mean which you want) then there should be cache issue, please try to execute below magento 2 commands,

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento s:s:d

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Thanks pal. I have executed your command but it did not work.I will check the table to see how it goes.

Comment: The table shows this
 web/unsecure/base_url         | http://13.210.72.64/

Comment: The table shows my base_url :http://13.210.72.64/  but I do not why the site is not showing correctly after I changed the site's url from http://13.210.72.64/magento2 (it was working correctly) to http://13.210.72.64/

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful :) @RRRay

Answer (score 0):

you should copy all your website file to the web folder of your server like this :

in magento2/  folder run :

- cp -r * ../
- sudo chmod -R 777 ../
- cd ..
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  -php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- chmod -R 777 *